# evitar stackoverflow ao ler e popular relações

Tags: java, java-ee, algoritmo

eu estou fazendo uma biblioteca que popula um model qualquer com valores aleatorios, para ser usado em testes, mas acontece que quando eu tenho uma relação como abaixo, eu recebo um `StackOverflowException`

**Author**

```
@Entity
public class Author implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

e **Book**

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {


@ManyToOne
private Author author;
```

o codigo que faz a leitura dos campos é assim

```
public <T> T fakeIt(Class<T> clazz) throws FakerException {
if(clazz.getAnnotation(Entity.class) == null){
    throw new FakerException("The class "+ clazz.getName()+ "is not an entity");
}
try {
    T faked  = clazz.newInstance();
    for(Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()){
    if(f.getName().equals("serialVersionUID"))
        continue;

    System.out.println("Genearting value for "+f.getName() + " on " + f.getDeclaringClass());

    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(faked, getValueForField(f));
    }
    return faked;
} catch(Exception e){
    throw new FakerException(e);
}
}

private Object getValueForField(Field f) throws Exception {
if(f.isAnnotationPresent(UseGenerator.class)){
    Generator<?> gen = (Generator<?>) f.getAnnotation(UseGenerator.class).generator().newInstance();
    return gen.genearte();

} else if(f.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToOne.class)){
    return fakeIt(f.getType());

} else if(f.isAnnotationPresent(OneToMany.class)){
    Class<?> toFake = extractTypeFromList(f);

    List<Object> fakedObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    fakedObjects.add(fakeIt(toFake));
    }

    return fakedObjects;
}
// Other types
String clazzType = f.getType().getSimpleName();
Generator<?> generator = defaultGenerators.get(clazzType.toLowerCase());

if(generator != null)
    return generator.genearte();

return null;
}

private Class<?> extractTypeFromList(Field f) {
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) f.getGenericType();
Class<?> type = (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

return type;
}
```

no caso, `fakeIt` é a função que gera os valores aleatorios. nesse caso, ele cai no campo `books` e quando chama novamente o `fakeIt`, vai tentar criar um novo `Author` que vai cair no campo `books` e assim por diante.
qual a melhor forma de evitar isso?

Comment: Poderia adicionar o erro à pergunta? A princípio não vejo onde pode ocorrer um `StackOverflow`. Esse `fakeIt` acaba por chamar esse mesmo método?

Comment: o `fakeIt` chama o metodo `getValueForField(Field F)` que chama novamente o `fakeIt` em caso de relacionamento. posso postar o codigo todo se ajudar

Comment: Poste sim, pelo menos o método getValueForField e o fakeIt.

Comment: @Dener editado!

Comment: **Luiz**, o `StackOverflow` é por causa da relação bidirecional: quando vai criar um `author` ele cria uma lista de `book` e esses também tentarão criar um `author`, a partir dai segue em loop. Você terá que procurar tratar as relações bidirecionais.

Comment: Faz uma lógica mais ou menos assim: crie `checkIfFieldHasClass(field, clazz, faked)` nesse método obtenha a classe do `field` verificando se essa classe tem o `clazz` como atributo, se tiver,`set` a instância sua criada `faked`, se não peça pra gerar esse valor.

Comment: legal, deu certo. você poderia postar como resposta pra eu aceitar?

Comment: Ok! Desculpe a demora pra responder! Resolvendo uns bugs aqui que acabei ficando sem tempo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Luiz**

A causa do `StackOverflow` é a relação bidirecional entre as classes `Book` e `Author`.

Quando você cria um `author` e tenta dar valores aos atributos, é criado um `List<Book>`, e cada elemento dessa lista também irá criar `Author`, que por sua vez cria um nova lista de livros e a partir dai segue em loop.

Para resolver o problema, você terá que procurar tratar as relações ***bidirecionais***.

Assim como disse no comentário, você pode resolver o problema criando um método que ao buscar o valor do `field` você checa se o próprio objeto `fake` não é o atributo do field, algo como:

```
private boolean checkIfFieldHasClass(Field f, Class<?> clazz){
   Class<?> fieldClass = f.getClass();

   for (Field declaredField : fieldClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (declaredField.getClass().equals(clazz)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Se o `field` possuir um atributo do tipo `clazz`, então `set` a instância  `faked` nesse atributo, do contrário peça pra gerar esse valor.

No comentário eu passei o `faked` como parâmetro também por equívoco. É melhor que deixe esse método acima retornando um `boolean` para que fique mais legível e que possa usar para outros momentos.